# Google Analytics GA - purchase event

Tags: google-analytics

I can't sent purchase event to google analytics. I can send others events if i use "ga('enet', 'event' ... " but code below do not working.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Success Page</title>
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i.GoogleAnalyticsObject = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga("create", "UA-XXXX-Y");
            ga('require', 'ec');
            ga('set', 'currencyCode', 'USD');
            ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);

            ga('ec:addProduct', {
                'id': "8500830",
                'name': "TEST",
                'price': "2.9100",
                'quantity': "1.0000"
            });
            ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
                'action': 'purchase',
                'affiliation': "TEST",
                'id': "000000111",
                'revenue': "15.9100",
                'shipping': "13.0000",
                'tax': "0.0000"
            });
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I do not see any errors in chrome dev tools, but this event dosen't appear in "Real-time -> Conversion".
Any suggestion why?

Answer (score 1):

E-commerce transactions are not reported as *'event'* in google analytics so it's OK if you don't see it in Real-time report.
In this case, transaction data are sent alongside pageview hit so only corresponding pageview will appear in Real-Time.
Check the Conversions>Ecommecre reports to check if your transactions data are processed properly.